# IOS How to pass variable valet the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer

I am sending users location to the server through web service, in the response I get interval to send next location. I am using the following call to send locations using timer but when I get the different value the timer still uses the old value. I also tried to invalidate the timer to set the new value but seems not working

I have global variable

```
long counter= 10;


self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:counter target:self selector:@selector(updateLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)updateLocation {
CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;
....
counter = 30;
}
```

I followed the couple of post from stack overflow but did not get it working.

In short, I need to send the updated location based on the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@interface MyClass()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat counter;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set initial value for timer
    self.counter = 10;
    [self resetTimer];
}

//...
- (void)resetTimer
{
    [self.timer invalidate]
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.counter target:self selector:@selector(updateLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)updateLocation 
{
    CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;
    //...
    self.counter = 30;
    [self resetTimer];
}
//...
- (void)dealloc
{
    //invalidate timer to avoid zombie objects  (EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash)
    [self.timer invalidate];
}
@end
```